# Shadow DOM : what is shadow Dom and How to edit something inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, browser, shadow-dom

I read many articles regarding shadow DOM but not clear about this. Can
anyone tell what is shadow DOM and how to add one for below code?

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="box"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/web-component/8239/getting-started-with-web-component/26500/shadow-dom-hello-world#t=201702140841345786364

Answer (score 3):

Shadow DOM is just an abstraction for DOM and CSS which is not included in the main document's DOM.

One example where Shadow DOM is used is in browsers. When you create an `<input type="range" />`
Chrome (or another Webkit-powered browser) will probably render a slider web component. While this slider is not part of the main document's DOM, the browser leverages the Shadow DOM to show this.

Shadow DOM is used heavily in cases where the presentation may differ from the code, mostly for preventing CSS leaking into the main component. You can find this pattern in many popular CSS frameworks.

In order to attach a "shadow" element you can use the [Shadow DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM), like so:

```
var shadow = document.querySelector('#box').attachShadow({ 
  mode: 'open' 
});
shadow.innerHTML = '<p>A box in the shadows</p>';
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a Shadow DOM to your code, add this script at the end of your HTML file:

```
<script>
    //create a Shadow DOM
    var shadowRoot = box.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )

    //add some content
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = 'RTFM!'
</script>
```

The Shadow DOM is rendered instead of the initial DOM tree (called the Light DOM).

---

You can also insert content of the Light DOM in the Shadow DOM with the help of `<slot>` elements:

```js
function add() {
  box.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
     .innerHTML = `
      <style>
        ::slotted( span ) { 
          color: blue ; 
          font-style: italic ; 
          outline: none !important ; 
          min-width: 0 !important; 
        }
      </style>
      Hello <slot name="Name"></slot>!`
}
```

```css
#box [contenteditable] {
  outline: 1px solid lightgray ;
  display: inline-block ;
  min-width: 50px ;
}
```

```html
<div id=box>
  Type your name:
  <span slot="Name" contenteditable>Mickey</span>
  <br><button onclick="add()">Add Shadow</button>
</div>
```